# Impedance matching of an amplifier circuit with a filter at the input and output

Tags: amplifier, filter, impedance, impedance-matching, microwave

I created an amplifier circuit with a filter on the output.

[image]

I did impedance matching on the input and then did matching on the output as well. From the graphs below, is the circuit more matched?

Picture of the amplifier itself with the filter:
[image]

Amplifier with filter with impedance matching at the input:

[image]

Amplifier with filter with impedance matching at input and output:
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to match the input impedance to? What are you trying to match the output impedance to?

Comment: trying to match the output impedance and input impedance to the hmc414 amplifier and the DEA142450BT-3028A1 filter for 2.45Ghs bandwidth

Comment: Let me ask another way. What is driving your amplifier (plus filters)? And what is your amplifier (plus filters) driving?

Comment: Sorry, I'm already saying. On the input there is port 1, which has Z = 50 Ohm, on the output there is port 2 which also has Z = 50 Ohm. I put the link to the block diagram below: 
https://imgur.com/tDKauKi

Comment: I'm doing simulations in AWR so I don't know why it's different. I count it for S parameters, specifically S11 and S22. The supervisor told me to put these points at 2.45GHz in the middle of the Smith chart. I put this graph below. https://imgur.com/Di7ubb4

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Do you perhaps know what this is about, and how to do it?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yeah, I have high-pass filter 2.425 GHz and I need to match it to 2.45 GHz

Comment: To be honest, I'm struggling with how to work out impedance matching or reflection coefficients from a Bode chart. Maybe someone else can jump in, or maybe I can figure it out.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy It's plotting the S11 and S22 (forward and reverse reflections) over frequency. So 0 dB means the signal is fully reflected. Generally want very large negative dB values.

Comment: @Michael. Thank-you. Do you know how to go a step further and determine whether the input and output impedances are matched to 50\$\Omega\$? Or is it a relative thing? Where perfect match would be -\$\infty\$ dB, and one just has to make a value judgment about whether, say -40dB is "good enough"?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy As far as I know, you need to pick an impedance value to get the S11, S22. One definition is S11 = (Zl - Zo)/(Zl + Zo), where Zl is a load impedance and Zo  is the reference impedance. For example, if you want to match amplifier input impedance to a 50Ω line, Zo = 50, and to minimize reflection Zl = 50. This is a perfect match, and as you mentioned, -inf dB. You'd have to make a judgement on what reflection is good enough. -40dB is 99% of a voltage transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

In your comments you specify that the operating frequency is 2.45GHz (correct me if I'm wrong). For a well matched system S11 and S22 are small linear values, meaning negative dB.

In your first plot your S11 and S22 are ~ -10dB at 2.45GHz, meaning 31.6% of an oncoming signal is reflected. Not too good.

After your match S11 is ~ -17.5dB and S22 is ~ -27.5dB at 2.45GHz. Now 13.3% of the wave reflects at the input, and only 4.2% reflects at the output. Overall a good improvement.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Thank you very much for your help, in that case it comes out that such a fit is acceptable. Then I still have a question about the stability of the circuit. Stability on smith chart looks like this: https://imgur.com/hdqrhpM Is this correct? Because I can't understand why it is like "behind" the range.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, I've never dealt with stability circles on the smith chart. That question is probably different enough to warrant a separate post where maybe someone else can answer. In the meantime I'll leave a link that may help answer the question: https://www.mwrf.com/technologies/components/article/21846567/ensure-stability-in-amplifier-designs